# Trouble writing serial port for React native windows c++ native module

Tags: c++, windows, react-native, react-native-windows, react-native-modules

This is my first time writing in C++ and using UWP. Currently, im having issues writing serial port in C++, it works fine with C# using System.IO.Ports. But with C++, there's alot of difference.

I'm currently getting error "[Error: Promise destroyed.]" with Async i assume because of "devices.Completed(...)".

How can I solve this issue?

CPP Native Module

```
#pragma once

#include "JSValue.h"
#include "NativeModules.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Microsoft::ReactNative;

namespace winrt::ReactNativeSerial
{

    REACT_MODULE(ReactNativeModule)
        struct ReactNativeModule
    {
        
        REACT_INIT(Initialize)
            void Initialize(ReactContext const& reactContext) noexcept
        {
            m_reactContext = reactContext;
        }


        REACT_METHOD(sampleMethod)
            void sampleMethod(std::string stringArgument, int numberArgument, std::function<void(std::string)>&& callback) noexcept
        {
            // TODO: Implement some actually useful functionality
            callback("Received numberArgument: " + std::to_string(numberArgument) + " stringArgument: " + stringArgument);
        }

        REACT_METHOD(connectSerial)
            void connectSerial(hstring& const portName, ReactPromise<void> promise) noexcept
        {
            try {
                auto aqs = SerialDevice::GetDeviceSelector(portName);
                IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection> devices = DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(aqs);

                devices.Completed([&](IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection> const& operation, AsyncStatus status) {
                    if (status == AsyncStatus::Completed)
                    {
                        DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = operation.GetResults();
                        if (deviceCollection.Size() > 0)
                        {
                            DeviceInformation deviceInfo = deviceCollection.GetAt(0);
                            serialDevice = SerialDevice::FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id()).get();
                            if (serialDevice)
                            {
                                serialDevice.BaudRate(9600);
                                serialDevice.DataBits(8);
                                serialDevice.Parity(SerialParity::None);
                                serialDevice.StopBits(SerialStopBitCount::One);
                                promise.Resolve();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                promise.Reject(L"Failed to open serial port");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            promise.Reject(L"No serial devices found");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        promise.Reject(L"Failed to retrieve device information");
                    }
                    });
            }
            catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex) {
                promise.Reject(ex.message().c_str());

            }
            catch (...) {
                promise.Reject(L"Something went wrong...");

            }

        }

        REACT_METHOD(closeSerial)
            void closeSerial(ReactPromise<void> promise) noexcept
        {
            serialDevice.Close();
            promise.Resolve();
        }

    private:
        ReactContext m_reactContext{ nullptr };
        SerialDevice serialDevice{ nullptr };
    };

} // namespace winrt::ReactNativeSerial
```

React Native Code

```
ReactNativeModule.connectSerial("COM4").then((d: any) => console.log(d)).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

I expect to get connection established with Serial Communication and able to readline from the connection using C++

Comment: Mmm.. I'm not familiar with react, but you receive promises by value as an argument, that's a  copy of some object. Unless it's some thin proxy, the object is local to the function and, being an argument passed by value, can be destroyed after its last use inside of function (difference of C++ from C#). Which may mean issues with lifespan and race conditions for you.